# Rake Task Misfire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I've got a rake file that performs a find and replace operation on certain text files.  When I type this at the terminal:

```
rake rename:changename[Funk]
```

I'd like the rake file to change every instance of the term `Framework` to `Funk`.  The problem is that the code currently changes `Framework` to `new_name` instead.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
namespace :rename do    
  desc 'changes the name of the app'
  task :changename, :new_name do
    file_names = ['config/environments/test.rb', 'config/environments/production.rb', 'config/environment.rb']
    file_names.each do |file_name|
      text = File.read(file_name)
      File.open(file_name, "w") { |file| file << text.gsub("Framework", :new_name.to_s) }
    end   
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are effectively passing `"new_name"` to `gsub` every time. This is because `:new_name.to_s` simply returns the string representation of the `:new_name` symbol.

You already allow the user to pass arguments to your task:

```
task :change_name, :new_name
  # ...
end
```

However, you are not actually *receiving* the argument array, which is yielded to the block given to the `task` method as the second formal parameter:

```
task :change_name, :new_name do |task, args|
  args.with_defaults new_name: 'Funk'
  # ...
end
```

With the arguments in hand, all you need to do is retrieve the new name:

```
file << text.gsub 'Framework', args[:new_name]
```